# Grails 3.0 Searchable plugin

Tags: grails, gradle

I've tried to use the [searchable plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/searchable) in grails 3.0, but I am not sure whether it is compatible or not.

I've added

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:searchable"
```

to the dependencies. The build completes but yields a NotSearializableException:

```
> Configuring > 1/1 projects > Resolving dependencies ':agent' > Resolving dependencies ':
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.949 secs

| Error Error initializing classpath: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultModuleVersionSelector
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultModuleVersionSelector
| Error Error initializing classpath: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultModuleVersionSelector
```

Can I use the searchable plugin in Grails 3.0 or do I have to switch to a previous grails version? The searchable plugin is not listed in the

```
grails list-plugins
```

command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you took the instructions from contains the following disclaimer:

> This portal is for Grails 1.x and 2.x plugins. Grails 3 plugins are available in Bintray https://bintray.com/grails/plugins

There currenly is no version of this plugin for grails 3.x